# Transition count for user product purchases in online retail

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, markov-chains

I am trying to build Markov chain user transition matrix from scratch but got stuck in dictionary value assignments. Below is the sample code

```
## user purchase sequence seperated by '|' at different time intervals
## lets say in first purchase user bought 3 4 12 23 45 41 25 these products then 4 5 12 17 19 25 46 3 and so on
user_purchase = '3 4 12 23 45 41 25|4 5 12 17 19 25 46 3|39 12 3 23 50 24 35 13|42 34 17 19 46'
## I need to find the transition count from first purchase to second and so on
## e.g 3-1 is 0 , 3-2 is 0 , 3-3 is 0 , 3-4 is 1
## hence output should be {...,2:[(0,0),(0,0),.....], 3:[(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(1,1), ...], 4:[...]} its a dictionary of list with tuples

### lets say its the total no of products ranging from 1 to 50 that user can buy
prod = range(1,51)

### initializing a dictionary of list with tuples
t = (0,0)
list1= []
for _ in range(len(prod)):
    list1.append(t)
user_tran = {}
for p in prod:
    user_tran[p]= list1


# def trans_matrix(prod_seq):
basket_seq = user_purchase.split('|')
iteration = len(basket_seq)
for j in range(iteration-1):
    trans_from = basket_seq[j]
    trans_to = basket_seq[j+1]
    tfrom = map(int,trans_from.split(' '))
    print tfrom
    tto = map(int,trans_to.split(' '))
    for item in tfrom:
### problem here is in each iteration the default value for all keys is updated from [(0,0),(0,0),....] to item_list
        item_list = user_tran[item]   ### seems problem here
        for i in range(len(prod)):
            if i+1 in tto:
               temp =  item_list[i]
               x = list(temp)
               x[0] = x[0] +1
               x[1] = x[1] +1
               item_list[i] = tuple(x)
            else:
                temp = item_list[i]
                x = list(temp)
                x[0] = x[0]
                x[1] = x[1] + 1
                item_list[i] = tuple(x)
        user_tran[item] = item_list  ### list updation should only be for item specified as key in user_tran but all keys are updated with same value
```

> user_tran[3][1:5]
>
> Out[38]: [(0, 23), (15, 23), (7, 23), (7, 23)]

Desired Output

0 transition from 3 to 1,2 in 3 sequences of purchases at a different time and product three being present in first three purchase sequence.
But there is two transition from 3-3

> [(0,3),(0,3),(2,3),...till product 50]

Comment: Can you explain more what your dictionary of list of tuples mean?

Comment: what I am trying to do is, Lets say there are 5 products in a store and user purchases 1,3,4 in first visit and 3,2,5 in next so the transition from 1st visit to 2nd given by a probability matrix. 
e.g for product 1 possible transitions here are
1-1,1-2,1-3,1-4,1-5 and 
actual transitions 
1-3,1-2,1-5
hence output dict of list of tuples should look like 
{1:[(0,1),(1,1),(1,1),(0,1),(1,1)], 2:[...]}
here is list of tuples first tuple
(0,1) means transition from 1-1, 0 implies 1-1 does not happen and 1 indication transition from 1st to 2nd purchase.

Comment: The problem here is the I am not able to assign a value to dictionary selectively based on key whenever I try to update list value in dictionary specific to a key all keys are updated with same values. I don't know If I am assigning to the dictionary of list 'user_tran' list value incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the reason for that, but I tried to implement it using numpy array without any tuples and dictionaries.

My output is not the same as your expected output, but I did exactly what you aimed to do with dictionary. It is just translation of dictionary-list version to numpy array version. May be it will help you.

```
import numpy as np

user_purchase = '3 4 12 23 45 41 25|4 5 12 17 19 25 46 3|39 12 3 23 50 24 35 13|42 34 17 19 46'
prod = range(0, 50)
user_tran = np.zeros((50,50,2))
basket_seq = user_purchase.split('|')
iteration = len(basket_seq)
for j in range(iteration-1):
    trans_from = basket_seq[j]
    trans_to = basket_seq[j+1]
    tfrom = map(int,trans_from.split(' '))
    tfrom = [x-1 for x in tfrom]
    tto = map(int,trans_to.split(' '))
    tto = [x - 1 for x in tto]
    for item in tfrom:
        item_list = user_tran[item, :, :]
        for i in range(len(prod)):
            if i + 1 in tto:
                temp = item_list[i, :]
                item_list[i, :] = np.array([temp[0] + 1, temp[1] + 1])
            else:
                temp = item_list[i, :]
                item_list[i, :] = np.array([temp[0], temp[0] + 1])
        user_tran[item, :, :] = item_list
print user_tran[2, 1:5, :]
```

user_tran form is as following: NxMx2 where N is a number of keys in your dictionary version, M is a number of items in your store and 2 is instead of tuple with 2 values. For example: to get 3rd key in your dictionary, and from 1 to 4th items in your list you have to write

```
user_tran[2, 1:5, :] #instead of user_tran[3][1:5]
```

because array starts with 0 index but not 1.

and you will get 4x2 matrix where 4 is a number of elements from your list and 2 is 2 values of your tuples.

Comment: Thank You Batyr! 
But I am trying to implement using regular data Structures for computation on distributed platform using spark, as actual data set has around 50000 products and more than million users. Don't know how I can work with np arrays in closure functions.

item_list = user_tran[item]  

I think here location reference is passed rather than value causing problem.